# Mostrar usuario logeado en php

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Hola estoy diseñando un pequeño sistema, quisiera que el usuario que inicio sesión se imprimiera en la parte superior por ejemplo "**Bienvenido+(nombre del usuario)**"  He intentado de muchas formas pero no lo puedo lograr, agradecería mucho su ayuda.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form class="user" action="index.php" method="post">

<div class="form-group">

<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" name="user" placeholder="Nombre de usuario">

</div>
<div class="form-group">

<input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user" name="pass" placeholder="Clave">

</div>

<button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block"> Entrar</button>

</form>
```

Y acá el código php, intente de muchas formas para intentar capturar el usuario e imprimir el usuario

```
if (isset($_POST["login"])) {

    include("global/conexion.php");

    $user = ($_POST['user']);
    $pass = ($_POST['pass']);

    $sentenciaSQL = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbusuarios WHERE username=:username AND password=:password LIMIT 1");

    $sentenciaSQL->bindParam("username", $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sentenciaSQL->bindParam("password", $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sentenciaSQL->execute();

    $registro = $sentenciaSQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $numeroregistros = $sentenciaSQL->rowCount();

    if ($numeroregistros >= 1) {
 
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $registro; //aquí uno de mis intentos
        header('Location:panel.php');
    } else {
        header('Location:index.php?fallo=true');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que necesitas es el manejo de sesiones, dentro de la sesion guardas los atributos que necesites, agregas el include en tu archivo  y seria cuestion de usar  $_SESSION["nombreUsuario"]
aqui el link para que puedas revisar su funcionamiento
unicamente  https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: Estoy usando:
session_start();
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $registro; y después uso echo($registro);

pero no funciona

Answer (score 0):

El `session_start()` debe estar colocado siempre al incio del documento cuando se trabaja con sesiones , si no nunca te va a funcionar , te dejo un [enlace](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php) sobre `session_start()` de la documentacion de PHP , donde indica sobre todo en la parte de **Notas** la cual menciona que `session_start()` **debe ser llamada antes de imprimir cualquier cosa en el navegador**.